# Implementing Selection Sort: Inputted array is changed along with returned array

Tags: java, arrays, selection-sort

I have a program that manipulates Cartesian points. At one spot in the program, I load my x and y values into a Point array. No big deal. But then, I want to sort this array by x values and set it to a new variable while still keeping the original array the way it is. 
The original array is "points" and the new array is defined as:

```
points1 = sortBy(points, "x");
```

The sortBy method is defined earlier as:

```
private static Point[] sortBy( Point[] pointsXY, String xOrY) {
  int min;
  Point[] inputPoints = pointsXY;

  if( xOrY == "x"){
  for( int i = 0; i < (inputPoints.length - 1); i++ ) {
     min = i;
     for( int j = i+1; j < inputPoints.length; j++ ) {
        if( inputPoints[j].getX() < inputPoints[min].getX()) min = j;  
     }
     // Swap points[i] and points[min]
     Point temp = inputPoints[i];
     inputPoints[i] = inputPoints[min];
     inputPoints[min] = temp;
  }
```

There is an "else if" block later that takes "y" instead. It then does: `return inputPoints;`

However, what I am getting when I am printing these arrays out are the exact same thing - two arrays sorted by x values. I have tested the output by just outputting the unsorted array, and it works fine. 
I also have tried using this method without it being static, which has given the same output.

Comment: `Point[] inputPoints = Arrays.copyOf(pointsXY, pointsXY.lenght);` should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

`Point[] inputPoints = pointsXY;` does not copy the array, it just creates a new name (`inputPoints`) for the same array. To create a copy of the array, you should use `Point[] inputPoints = pointsXY.clone();` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--)).

Comment: Ugh, of course it was something simple like that! Thanks, that worked like a charm!